# Picking from a set probability question

Tags: probability

If I had a set with $x$ elements and I read a random one $y$ times (picking with replacement), what would the average number of unique elements I had read as a function of $x$ and $y$? This is very similar to the [Coupon collector's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem).

Comment: Please expand on what you know about the problem and where you get stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  what is the probability that a particular element is read?  Now use the linearity of expectation to multiply by $x$.